# Is there a way to create a VBA script that changes the last row used in print area?

Tags: excel, vba, string, printing

So, I am trying to create a VBA code that will automatically change the print area of an excel worksheet to the last row with data.  Currently, I have a way to record the last row of the sheet, but not a way to convert that value into the end of the range.  My issue is with the second part of this code.  The idea I have is to make a string variable called "Test" combine the value of the variable `last_row` with the fixed column `O`.

Currently, the row ends at 400, so the print area would be `$B$2:$O$400`
I need the VBA script to know when more rows have been added and adjust the print area to be that new figure. example: `$B$2:$O$434`

```
Dim last_row as long

Sheets ("Main Tab").Select

last_row = cells(Rows.Count,1).end(xUp).Row

Dim Test as String

Test = "O$" & last_row

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:test"
```

Comment: ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:" & test

Comment: `xUp` needs to be `xlUp` the lower case `L` is missing here! Make sure you use `Option Explicit` so you get notified about such issues. Also I recommend to read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to get gid of your `Select` statement and the `ActiveSheet` too.

Answer (score 1):

If your other things are okay then problem is in putting `test` inside double quote. So, change it like

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$B$2:" & test
```